# Cordova with external login provider - not able to redirect to URL on physical device

Tags: android, cordova, oauth, typescript, redirect

I have an issue with redirect after login using external provider on mobile phone application. I am using Cordova + InBrowserApp plugin + TypeScript in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.

In the emulator (Ripple)  and the browser everything is working correctly becuase it's running on localhost. On the phone (Android) it does not... 
The location in the browser is set to: 
file:///android_asset/www/index.html and it looks like there is no web server to handle the redirect. 
I have set the redirect to:

```
AuthCompleted.html
/AuthCompleted.html
Localhost
/authCompleted.html
file:///android_asset/www/AuthCompleted.html
```

but the application is displaying that cannot redirect/ file does not exists.

To open the login window from the provider  I am using the below code

```
window.open
```

Everything is working correctly until I am trying to pass the authorization token to the phone.

This is the process:

1. Open the window and set the URL to point to my server - so I can start the login provider (Google/FB)
2. Correct redirect to Google/FB to provide the credentials
3. My server receives the token to make the callback to the login provider
4. My server sends the token to the browser (phone) using the parameter in the redirect URL - and here everything is crashing because the redirect does not happen on the phone.

What can be the issue here? How should I setup the URL redirect in Cordova so this will work?